# Static link ffmpeg with Rust in msys2

Tags: rust, ffmpeg, compilation

I'm trying to build ffmpeg with Rust with the library ffmpeg-next and staticlly link ffmpeg on Windows inside msys2 `ucrt64` environment,
When compile with `cargo build --release`
It throws many undefined reference errors

```
undefined reference to `ENGINE_load_builtin_engines'
undefined reference to `GdipBitmapSetPixel'
undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_CTX_free'
```

The setup:

```bash
pacman -S --needed $MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX-{rust,ffmpeg}
mkdir project 
cd project
cargo init --bin
cargo add ffmpeg-next -F static
```

The entrypoint `main.rs`

```rust
use ffmpeg_next;
fn main() {
    ffmpeg_next::init().unwrap();
}
```

Build command

```
cargo build --release
```